# Showing pop up messagebox in aspx.cs file - Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

So I have a web page with a list of products.  Next to each product is a hyperlink that the user clicks to generate a Word document and is available for the user to view.  Each product has an ID, sizes, etc...

I have code that executes in the aspx.cs code behind and a try-catch block that checks to see if the selected product has sizes.  If the product doesn't have any sizes then I want a pop-up messagebox to appear to alert the user that the sizes have not been recorded for the product yet and it cannot generate the document.

My question is, how can I accomplish this?  I have tried the Response.Write(...) function and the Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(...) function.  Both build fine and execute but no pop-up message.  I know I've used the Response.Write() function before and it's worked in VS2013 but doesn't seem to work in VS2015.

Below is my code.  Any help/suggestions are appreciated.

```
    //Alert the user to fix the data if the parent sizes are missing from the Sizes column in ProductMart
    try
    {
        //This is set to null to execute Catch block
        parentSizeList = null;
        pSizes = parentSizeList.Split(',');
        foreach (var p in pSizes)
            parentSizes.Add(p);
    }
    catch 
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "msgbox", "alert('TEST');", true);

        Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('The Measurement Sizes are missing in the Product Mart for the parent product. " + 
            " Please fix the data for Pack Number " + product.PackNumber + " to print inspection document');</script>");
    }
```

Comment: code looks fine.check the page source. is your javascript added or not

Comment: It does not appear to be added when I do the view page source after clicking the hyperlink to generate the code.

Comment: Alternatively, you could check for those size values when build your list of products to display and not present the link next to products where it can't create the document.

Comment: Agreed.  I've already considered it.  That may be my only option as I still cannot seem to find a solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a way to do this using an UpdatePanel.  Below is the code located in my .aspx page that uses a javascript alert to display the message that's defined in the code behind.  I added the UpdatePanel to the very bottom of my .aspx page.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel id="UpdatePanel1" class="noSizesUpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert('<%=message%>');
        </script>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In my Page_Load in the code behind, I did an `UpdatePanel1.Visible = false` to hide the alert box until needed.

I created a public property `public string message;` in the code behind.

Then in my try-catch block:

```
try
{
    //Do stuff
}
catch (Exception)
{
    message = "Whatever you want your message to be";
    UpdatePanel1.Visible = true;
}
```